# What's the best way to count unique visitors on my webpage?

Tags: php, cookies

I create a php class to count unique visitors on my webpage, my ideas is create a cookie that stays on the visitor computer until 23:59 of the current day, if the cookie exite it means that the site has already been visited and does not do anything, if it does not exist then create the cookie and account new visit

this is the code I have for creating the code, if the cookie exite it return false, if not create the cookie and return true.

**

```
function CriakCookieDia(){  
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[sha1('visita')])){  
        $tempoAteAoFimDoDia=strtotime('tomorrow') - time();
        setcookie(sha1('visita'), true,  time()+$tempoAteAoFimDoDia);
        return true;    
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }
```

**

but I'm not having the expected result, instead of unique visits, it's like I count the number of views on the site, it's like I'm not creating the cookie, what's wrong about my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expiry time needs to be a timestamp for a specific date/time.

This code give a date in 1970.

```
strtotime('tomorrow') - time(); // 01/01/1970 11:15:01
```

So your code was just a bit too complicated, set the cookie expiry time to `strtotime('tomorrow')` which will give tomorrows date at `00:00:00` i.e. the beginining of tomorrow

This code, run at 28/06/2018 13:40:00 will give:

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime('tomorrow')); // 29/06/2018 00:00:00
```

Try this instead

```
function CriakCookieDia(){  
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[sha1('visita')])){  
        setcookie(sha1('visita'), true, strtotime('tomorrow'));
        return true;    
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank man, the cookie is working, but it seems that there is something more than this, I test the code online and its working as expected but the visits continue to increase as if everyone was using anonymous mode in the browser or as insted of unice visits its counting page views,

Comment: Hi, that kinda depends upon what you are doing with the results of this function call.